# Make nginx wait x seconds before returning a 502

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, php-fpm, fastcgi

I think `fastcgi_read_timeout` is what I need here, but would like to get expert confirmation on my use-case! Thanks.

--

I have nginx doing fastcgi relay to a php-fpm instance.

The fpm instance, from time to time needs to be restarted. This can take upwards of 1 to 2 seconds. If a request comes in during this time, nginx will give the user a 502 error.

> Ideally we will have a cluster of fpm processes for rolling restarts, but that's out of scope at this time.

My goal is to have NGINX wait, up to X s/ms before returning a 502 to the user if the cgi-relay is not available.

Here is a general idea of what I'm working with:

```
  location ~ ^/path/to(/|$) {
    include includes/php.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_SCHEME $http_x_forwarded_proto;

    # Assume some timeout param can be added here??

    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe a 502 Gateway timeout is returned when your php gateway is anything but up. For this reason, the time out is ideally controlled in php.

In your `php.ini` file look for the following line:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 60
```

Change from 60 seconds to whatever you need then restart both and test the time out again.

Comment: So, you're correct `fastcgi_read_timeout` is not what I need, that's how long it waits for a response from cgi. Changing the value didn't affect my use-case at all. The reason I can't use your solution is because the php-fpm process is literally being stopped and restarted, so I can't handle it in php (since php isnt listening). I need to somehow allow nginx to just be more graceful in how long it will wait for the cgi back end to be available. Appreciate your insight regardless.

Comment: The stopping and restarting is actually the recycling behavior of the FPM Process manager. Once a php-7.3fpm process processes a certain amount of php scripts, the process manager kills it and restarts it fresh. This helps php7.3-fpm stay healthy. The no downtime part of it is when you edit the pool of processes that php7.3-fpm can use. These settings can be finely tuned in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. This is the config file for php7.3-fpm